# How to login to repository using pysvn&

Tags: python, authentication, pysvn

i'm a total freshman in python, i have 2.7 version on my computer.
I need to download latest revision from repository.
My code is:

```
import pysvn 
svn_url = "https://..."
    client = pysvn.Client()
```

how should i login there? I could not find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

By defining a call back function to the SVN client

```
def svn_login (realm, username, may_save):  
  return True, svn_login_name, svn_login_password, False

client = pysvn.Client ()  
client.callback_get_login = svn_login
```

Check that: [How to catch login failures with PySVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625344/how-to-catch-login-failures-with-pysvn)

Comment: all time i tried this i have " svn: E235000: In file 'C:\Win32Svn\SVN-1.8.1-24\src-1.8.1\subversion\libsvn_subr\dirent_uri.c' line 1571: assertion failed (! svn_path_is_url(relative))"

Comment: hang on, will try it :)

Comment: Worked fine for me. Check the version of your pysvn library and also the SVN version which the library is built against.